# Video file is not upload in php

Tags: php

I have used this code to upload video on the server

```
 $target = "../images/video/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 
 $pic='images/video/'.($_FILES['file']['name']); 
 //Writes the photo to the server 

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 
 }
```

and also i have tried this

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

its giving be back this

```
Array ( [file] => Array 
                 ( 
                   [name] => Ankhian Nu Ren De - Quratulain Balouch (Studio Version) [HD] - YouTube.mp4 
                   [type] => [tmp_name] => 
                   [error] => 1 
                   [size] => 0 
                 ) 
   )
```

so tell me what is the issue

Comment: `[error] => 1 ` is the issue in case you think having error is indication of absence of issues

Comment: There may be folder permission issue and/or max_filesize issue

Comment: folder have 0777 permission set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php):

```
UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.
```

Basically, the file is too large. You will need to change your settings to allow for larger file uploads. In your php.ini file set the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 120M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 120M
```

If you have a shared host using `ini_set()` [most likely will not work](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php). But you can try to use .htaccess (but this may not work as well):

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 120M
php_value post_max_size 120M
```

Comment: i have use it before
@ini_set( ‘upload_max_size’ , ’120M’ );
@ini_set( ‘post_max_size’, ’120M’);
@ini_set( ‘max_execution_time’, ’1000′ );

Comment: example: upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M

Comment: @user3636439 You can't alter that directive with `ini_set()`

Comment: so how can i do this?

Comment: You need to be able to edit the php.ini file. If you're on a shared host you're probably out of luck.

Comment: yes i have shared host.

Comment: See my updated answer for a possible workaround

Comment: this is work for me update your answer with this i will accept your answer [PHP]

; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize=120M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads=100

Comment: Which part do you want added to the answer?

Comment: i have use this in php.ini [PHP]


upload_max_filesize=120M

max_file_uploads=100